# D3 multi series line graph

Tags: d3.js, scatter-plot, linegraph

I am trying to create line + scatterplot on several categories of data from several countries over the years.

The problem is that the line graph continues from one data category to next data category. 
I looked at an exmaple from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955 but didn't quite understand what changes I need to implement.

Should I seperate data using  elements? Or, is there simpler way to do this?

```
var line = d3.svg.line()

        .x(function(d)
            {return xScale(d.Year);
            })
        .y(function(d){
            return yScale(d.Value);
            })
```

// appending circles for scatterplot

```
var circle = svg.selectAll('circle')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
```

// drawing lines.

```
svg.append('path')
    .datum(data)
    .attr("d",line)
    .style("stroke","blue")
    .style("stroke-width","1px")
    .style("fill","none")
```

// Portion of CSV data file. Data repeats for several countries.

```
Variable,Unit,Country,Year,Value,Flags
"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2001",94,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2002",94,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2003",95,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2004",95,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2005",95,

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1980",33, 

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1981",40,

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1982",48,

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1983",55,

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1984",62,

"Measles","% of children immunised","Australia","1983",68,

"Measles","% of children immunised","Australia","1984",68,

"Measles","% of children immunised","Australia","1985",68,
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the code you paste is few, i just guess if the problem is the data structure you passed to the chart is not correct.

In exmaple from [http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955#index.html), the chart classified by cities, the data passed to the chart are classified cities array:

```
var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

city.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

The data structure of cities array is like below:

New York -> Array[...]

San Fran -> Array[...]

Austin -> Array[...]

See below image for detail:

[image]

Hope it helps.